# How to translate between .htaccess and web.config?

Tags: .htaccess, iis, web-config, url-rewriting

I don't have any access to control panel tools, don't have a clue how to do this correctly. I created the following rewrite rules to save me a ton of work - but that's not worked out too well upon realising the server's Microsoft.

```
RewriteRule ^scotsman-photo-products-([A-Za-z0-9-_]+)/?$ scotsman-photo-products.php?pg=$1 
RewriteRule ^make-scotsman-photo-([A-Za-z0-9-_]+)/?$ make-scotsman-photo.php?pg=$1
```

seems any changes made to the config file create a 500 error - is it possible the server will not allow any changes unless through "official" routes?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <defaultDocument>
            <files>
                <add value="index.php" />
            </files>
        </defaultDocument>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Is the current content.

Comment: I saw you comments below, is this a dedicated server or are you using a web hosting offer?

Comment: I believe below he states his company is renting a server from 1&1.

Comment: It's a dedicated server with 1and1 running software for personalised print products. I help out once a while tidying up the site content (it's a friends company) but he struggles to get good staff to keep it up to date so it's never in profit. Including rewrite rules was a way for me to help him with SEO and make it easier for staff to add content. I've essentially got the site created from five words in a text file and some PHP juggling. Frankly I'm kinda fatigued with it at the moment and just revered to querystrings.

Comment: My point being if this is a dedicated server you should be able to install the Rewrite Module and use @Leeish valid answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>
    <rule name="Rule Name" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^scotsman-photo-products-([A-Za-z0-9-_]+)/?$" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
        <add input="{SCRIPT_NAME}" pattern="^/(files|images|js|css|robots.txt|sitemap.xml|favicon.ico)($|/.*$)" negate="true" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Rewrite" url="scotsman-photo-products.php?pg={R:0}" />
</rule>
<rule name="Other Rule Name" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^make-scotsman-photo-([A-Za-z0-9-_]+)/?$" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
        <add input="{SCRIPT_NAME}" pattern="^/(files|images|js|css|robots.txt|sitemap.xml|favicon.ico)($|/.*$)" negate="true" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Rewrite" url="make-scotsman-photo.php?pg={R:0}" />
</rule>
</rules>
</rewrite>
```

I think that might work. Conditions are optional.

The first condition states not to use the rule if there is in fact a file at that location. The second is similar in that it stops if that is in fact a directory. The third makes the rule not run if the URL is a type found in the pattern.

Comment: Hmm doesn't seem to like that at all, even the slightest change to the existing web.config is creating a 500 error

Comment: Wrap it in this... I apologize... `<rewrite>
<rules>` and `</rewrite>
</rules>` Just to make sure nothing is crazy first add `<rewrite></rewrite>` Then `<rules></rules>` Then add one rule at a time. I don't have my config files in front of me at the moment, so just to make sure my syntax is correct add them one at a time and see where it breaks.

Comment: If you are running on IIS, I am pretty sure you need to install the rewrite module as well. This explans all about it. http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module I am not sure about running this under different windows environments, I run Win 2008 Server and IIS 7.5. What are you running. Here is where you can install the module from in case you haven't. http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite

Comment: Here is an entire Microsoft document about translating htaccess to webconfig. http://www.iis.net/learn/application-frameworks/install-and-configure-php-applications-on-iis/translate-htaccess-content-to-iis-webconfig

Comment: OK thanks you've been a lot of help, I've not got it working yet but I'm sure that's down to how the server is setup (Operating system : Windows Web Server 2008 R2 [with] SB Panel 10 (64 bit)
), unfortunately I don't know what I'm doing in there so don't want to touch it - I'm hoping that the hosting company will do the job.

Comment: Well for sure you need to install the rewrite module before the rewriting will work. Secondly, once you do, you can put my code inside the `system.webServer` tags. So as a sibling to you `defaultDocument` tag. That being said, I don't have the `defaultDocument` tag and don't know what it does and it could conflict with rewrite rules, I don't know.

Comment: I don't know what SB Panel is though. If you can't get to the IIS services manager, or install rewrite module on the machine you need to contact the hosting company and see what is installed. If you get a 500 with blank rules, you may not have the rewrite modile installe.d

Comment: I'll give you a laugh - the company I'm doing this for rents this dedicated server for £100 a month with 1&1. Last time we needed to have something modified on the server and asked "support" a question their response was "Google it". The default document tag sets the home page - I tried every possible combination of your code, I have zero doubt it is nothing but correct and it's a setup issue.

Comment: Yeah. Those cheap hosts can kill you. I'd switch. Most hosts do have URL rewriting though.

Comment: Can't find if there's a direct contact on this site - but would you be interested in taking this on as a paying job? Setting up the rewrite engine, installing IIS Service manager. Let me know your price (if it's possible to estimate) and I'll pass it on to the client. It'd certainly save me a lot of hassle and others in maintaining the site.

Comment: I'll start a bounty for you. Put your request in your question and maybe you'll get better help. I am not familiar enough with server setup to really provide you with a complete answer, but someone here might be. Also, possibly ask this question on server fault.

Comment: Ach it's OK - perhaps at a later date, you've been a great help and hoped to at least get you a spot of beer money.